# Average counts from HashMap using java 8 stream API?

Tags: dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map` of the following type

```
public class MapUtils {

    private Map<String, Integer> queryCounts = new HashMap<>();

public void averageCounters(){

    int totalCounts = queryCounts.values().stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    queryCounts = queryCounts.entrySet()
                             .stream()
                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                 Map.Entry::getKey,
                                 (Map.Entry::getValue)/totalCounts
    ));
}
```

This does not compile and shows error in this line `(Map.Entry::getValue)/totalCounts`. How do I fix this? Is there a better way to get achieve average over `Map` using Java 8 API?

**EDIT**:
Is this a better approach?

```
queryCounts.entrySet()
           .forEach(entry -> queryCounts.put(entry.getKey(),
                                   entry.getValue()/totalCounts));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want in-place modification, it's much better to use `Map.replaceAll` instead of Stream API:

```
int totalCounts = queryCounts.values().stream()
                             .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));
queryCounts.replaceAll((k, v) -> v/totalCounts);
```

However in your case this solution is problematic as division results will be rounded to an `int` number, thus you almost always will got zeroes in the result. Actually there's the same problem in your code. You probably want to have `Map<String, Double>` as the resulting type. So you probably need to create a completely new `Map`:

```
Map<String, Double> averages = queryCounts.entrySet().stream()
                                          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                                              e -> ((double)e.getValue())/totalCounts));
```

An alternative would be to have `queryCounts` declared as `Map<String, Double>` in the first place. This way you can use `replaceAll`:

```
double totalCounts = queryCounts.values().stream()
                             .collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Double::doubleValue));
queryCounts.replaceAll((k, v) -> v/totalCounts);
```

Finally there's also one more alternative which is the most efficient, but dirty. Your code assumes that original (non-averaged) `queryCounts` are unnecessary after `averageCounters()` is called. Thus you can keep `queryCounts` as `Map<String, Integer>` (which is more effective than counting to `Map<String, Double>`), but then change the `Map` values type like this:

```
double totalCounts = queryCounts.values().stream()
                             .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>)queryCounts;
map.replaceAll((k, v) -> ((Integer)v)/totalCounts);
Map<String, Double> averages = (Map<String, Double>)map;
queryCounts = null;
```

The similar trick is [performed](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#919) in JDK inside the `Collectors.groupingBy` implementation.